# PHP достать нужные даные из строки URL

Tags: php

Здравствуйте задача такая, имеем переменную с ссылкой, из этой ссылки нужно достать нужные данные, если быть конкретным то вот пример.
Имеем строку url "https://vk.com/id11111111?z=video11111111_12345" из нее нужно достать video11111111_12345 затем из него нужно вынуть 11111111 и 12345 присвоив их двум разным переменным. То есть имеем url с которого нам надо вынуть 11111111 и 12345. Это идентификатор юзера и объекта, они разные каждый раз, задача доставать их и обрабатывать дальше. 
Спасибо за ранние за помощь!

PHP 5.6

Answer (score 2):

Возможно есть более элегантное решение, но на первый взгляд как-то так:

```
$url = 'https://vk.com/id11111111?z=video11111111_12345';
$result = NULL;

parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $parse_str);
if (isset($parse_str['z']) && preg_match('|^video(\d*)_(\d*)$|i', $parse_str['z'], $parse_str)) {
  $result = [$parse_str[1], $parse_str[2]];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => string(8) "11111111"
  [1] => string(5) "12345"
}
```

Либо `NULL`, если входная ссылка не соответствует тому, что нам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное то что нужно!

Comment: Я бы радостью, я пробовал только мне выдает что нельзя от юзеров с рейтингом менее 15(

Comment: @Игорь вопрос снят... главное чтобы знали :)

Comment: имхо, нет смысла в `parse_url` если дальше все равно регулярки гонять (в которых кстати `\d+` а не `*` должны быть). Если делать с `parseUrl`, то удаляйте часть `video` и делайте `list($uid,$ vid) = explode("_", ...)`

Answer (score 2):

> *Нужно достать video11111111_12345 затем из него нужно вынуть 11111111 и 12345 присвоив их двум разным переменным*

Для этого используют регулярные выражения:

```
$str = 'https://vk.com/id11111111?z=video11111111_12345';

$userID = $objID = false;
! preg_match('~video(\d+)_(\d+)~', $str, $arr) ?: list(, $userID, $objID) = $arr;

// $userID и $objID - ID пользователя и объекта соответственно
```

---

**См.** [**демо**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc221fd92a876d31a2e1d652254a05e2cf56b27d)

Comment: krasivo........